# How to save data into a class after getting it from JSON?

Tags: json, swift

I found this question in one of the post made here, sadly with no answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940756/save-data-of-json-into-the-class

I have the same problem, I use a class to save the data from the server, that i actually get, but when the connection to the server ends all the variables turn into nill.

Is there any way to save the data from the JSON? Like for example:
When the user logs I get all the information to fill his profile page(Image, email, name), what do i need to do so i can save all that information to use later.

```
struct userAttemptNumber3:Decodable {
let nickname: String
let email: String
let idUser: String
let experience: String
let image: String
let inactive: String

static func readUtilizador (userID: String) -> Void{

    var infoAttempt:[String] = []

    let url = Parametro.perfilRead(userID: userID)
    let request = URL(string: url)


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request!){ (data, response, error) in
        do {
            guard let data = data else { return }

            let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

            //LEVOU CAST DE INT PARA STRING
            if let TestEmail = myJson["email"] as? String{
                infoAttempt.append(TestEmail)
            }

        } catch {
            print("Erro Attempt3")
        }

        //return infoAttempt
    }.resume()

}
```

}

Comment: `UserDefaults`, Property List or JSON file in Documents, Core Data and more. There are many ways.